# How to insert distinct and semi-distinct entries into table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I have a table `table1` having 2 columns `user_name` and `book_name`.

Now I want to insert entries such that the same user cannot have the same book name in another entry.

I was trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO table1(user_name, book_name) VALUES('random_user', 'random_book')
ON CONFLICT (user_name, book_name ) DO NOTHING;
```

But this was returning me a Postgres error 42P10.

Also, I want to know about how to enter entries in a table where it's one column may be the same but others should be different. For example, A table having three fields `user_name`, `book_name`, `quantity` in which a user can have the same book in different entries only if its quantity is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to define the unique constraint or index:

```
create table table1 (
    user_name text,
    book_name text,
    unique (user_name, book_name)
);

INSERT INTO table1(user_name, book_name)
    VALUES('random_user', 'random_book')
    ON CONFLICT (user_name, book_name ) DO NOTHING;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1d5f0109cf4754f43a5ac6027431177d) is a db<>fiddle.

Of course, this assumes that you are using Postgres 9.5 or later.